# Why is JS' recursive fibonacci function faster than so many other languages?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, fibonacci

I'm currently writing my own interpreter and benchmarked around with some languages for comparison.

The following pseudo-code recursive fibonacci function

```
fib(n) => n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

executed on my machine with `fib(32);` resulted in:

```
 - Py:   ~500ms (Python 3)
 - PHP:  ~300ms (PHP 7)
 - Java: ~72ms  (Java17)
 - C#:   ~30ms  (.NET Core 5)
 - JS:   ~24ms  (Chrome)
 - C/++: ~8ms   (current GCC)
```

How is this possible?
I've ran the function inside chrome's JS interpreter (dev console).
My own language, written in C as an interpreter compiling into bytecode, **takes 120ms.**

My first take was that JS looks at function calls and asynchronously starts them in parallel, waiting until both return - which would reduce the time needed (just for the first call) by almost half.

But I could be so wrong. How is JavaScript, in a Browser, in this scenario, faster or nearly as fast as C#, Java, etc.?

I am aware that a looped approach is a quintillion times faster in every case, but this is important to me and to my understanding of language design.

Thanks in advance to all you clever minds out there!

Comment: JavaScript definitely does not parallelize the recursive calls.

Comment: Spec gaurantees that JS cannot ever parallelize tasks at all.

Comment: I know, it'd be way too weird. I mean, it IS possible. It would be a wild form of optimization. Or they just pre-stored the first 1000 fibonacci numbers somewhere as constant values and look them up when the identifier "fib" is found, LOL.


edit: Apparently it's not possible according to CollinD, but it would be in general, is what I meant.

Comment: It's _not_ possible. A language with that optimization isn't javascript. The ecmascript spec provides a "run-to-completion" gaurantee.

Comment: Thank you for clearning that up, didn't know that. I'm from statically-typed-compiler-land and have little idea of how some interpreters work internally.

Comment: What have you measured exactly? Microbenchmarks are very simple to f... up.

Comment: clock cycles in C and the most accurate measuring tools i had for each language. And i can _feel_ the difference between 30ms and 300ms. It could be a bit off, but not by much.

Comment: Did you run each language 100-10000 times and average them out, or just once?

Comment: loops of 100, in average, C only once.

Comment: Too short. Run them for several seconds. Find a setting where Python runs for circa half minute.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is JIT-Compiled (just-in-time compiled, at least most implementations are), meaning that if it sees a function is called a lot with the same data type arguments, it will optimize the code to use more native data types instead of treating everything as an abstract type.

There's a talk by Franziska Hinkelmann called ["JavaScript engines - how do they even?"](https://youtu.be/p-iiEDtpy6I) that includes a lot more detail about how engines detect when to optimize and a bit more on how they do the optimization.

Comment: So you're saying it's using an integer rather than a double? That makes sense, Although would that really increase performance that much? It's still running inside a VM, needs to be read, etc.

Comment: I don't know if it's optimizing to an integer instead of a double (I'm not sure how much that would speed it up), but it's definitely optimizing to know that the argument is a number (either an int or double, I'm not sure it's specificity) instead of it needing to try to handle everything (like booleans, strings, or objects). AFAIK, it still checks the type each time to make sure that it wont be invalid as a result of the optimization, and if it ever recieves a non-number it throws away the optimized version in favor of one that works on all data types.

Comment: @Samathingamajig even then it doesnt make sense it beeing faster than C# considering that C# is actually using int in the background as native type :0